# How to create a Python extension that returns back a Polars Dataframe from Rust to Python with Pyo3?

Tags: python, rust, rust-polars, pyo3

I want to build a pyo3 extension module that creates a polars Dataframe in rust and then returns a python Dataframe. I am using maturin develop to develop and test these pyo3 extensions.

I was able to run [this example](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/tree/main/examples/python_rust_compiled_function) for creating a module that processes two Polars Series and then returns a Series into python. How can I modify `ffi.rs` to return back a Dataframe instead of a Series?

Here is the `ffi.rs` file:

```
use arrow::ffi;
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError;
use pyo3::ffi::Py_uintptr_t;
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::{PyAny, PyObject, PyResult};

/// Take an arrow array from python and convert it to a rust arrow array.
/// This operation does not copy data.
fn array_to_rust(arrow_array: &PyAny) -> PyResult<ArrayRef> {
    // prepare a pointer to receive the Array struct
    let array = Box::new(ffi::ArrowArray::empty());
    let schema = Box::new(ffi::ArrowSchema::empty());

    let array_ptr = &*array as *const ffi::ArrowArray;
    let schema_ptr = &*schema as *const ffi::ArrowSchema;

    // make the conversion through PyArrow's private API
    // this changes the pointer's memory and is thus unsafe. In particular, `_export_to_c` can go out of bounds
    arrow_array.call_method1(
        "_export_to_c",
        (array_ptr as Py_uintptr_t, schema_ptr as Py_uintptr_t),
    )?;

    unsafe {
        let field = ffi::import_field_from_c(schema.as_ref()).unwrap();
        let array = ffi::import_array_from_c(*array, field.data_type).unwrap();
        Ok(array)
    }
}

/// Arrow array to Python.
pub(crate) fn to_py_array(py: Python, pyarrow: &PyModule, array: ArrayRef) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    let schema = Box::new(ffi::export_field_to_c(&ArrowField::new(
        "",
        array.data_type().clone(),
        true,
    )));
    let array = Box::new(ffi::export_array_to_c(array));

    let schema_ptr: *const ffi::ArrowSchema = &*schema;
    let array_ptr: *const ffi::ArrowArray = &*array;

    let array = pyarrow.getattr("Array")?.call_method1(
        "_import_from_c",
        (array_ptr as Py_uintptr_t, schema_ptr as Py_uintptr_t),
    )?;

    Ok(array.to_object(py))
}

pub fn py_series_to_rust_series(series: &PyAny) -> PyResult<Series> {
    // rechunk series so that they have a single arrow array
    let series = series.call_method0("rechunk")?;

    let name = series.getattr("name")?.extract::<String>()?;

    // retrieve pyarrow array
    let array = series.call_method0("to_arrow")?;

    // retrieve rust arrow array
    let array = array_to_rust(array)?;

    Series::try_from((name.as_str(), array)).map_err(|e| PyValueError::new_err(format!("{}", e)))
}

pub fn rust_series_to_py_series(series: &Series) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    // ensure we have a single chunk
    let series = series.rechunk();
    let array = series.to_arrow(0);

    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        // import pyarrow
        let pyarrow = py.import("pyarrow")?;

        // pyarrow array
        let pyarrow_array = to_py_array(py, pyarrow, array)?;

        // import polars
        let polars = py.import("polars")?;
        let out = polars.call_method1("from_arrow", (pyarrow_array,))?;
        Ok(out.to_object(py))
    })
}
```